# Received 'ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index' error while scraping Yahoo Finance data for 10,000+ tickers

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

Running this code works great with less than a thousand tickers or symbols.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
import time
from yahooquery import Ticker
symbols = ['AAPL','GOOG','MSFT']
faang = Ticker(symbols)
faang.valuation_measures
df = pd.DataFrame(faang.valuation_measures)
df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

But if I put 10,000 or more tickers, I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Comment: according to https://yahooquery.dpguthrie.com/guide/ticker/financials/#valuation_measures valuation_mesures returns a panda dataframe. So I think it should not be passed to pd.DataFrame again.

Comment: I don't think calling pd.DataFrame on a dataframe would raise this error though. It appears to just return the dataframe as-is. @OP can you share the part where you "put 10,000 or more tickers"? When I run your code I get a dataframe with 26 rows, and I don't see a place to pass a number in your code.

Comment: Thank you, @iamjaydev!  I deleted the "pd.DataFrame" portion and it works (for the three tickers).  Will try it for 10,000+ tickers and see if the error stops (takes hours to run).

Comment: @ljdyer, thank you for your comment.  The 10,000 tickers/symbols part - right now it has three: "symbols = ['AAPL','GOOG','MSFT']"

Here it has eighteen: "symbols = ['WAVS','WAVSU','PSCE','MSSA','MSSAR','MSSAU','QABA','EBMT','GIAC','GIACU','ROSE','ROSEU','CLMB','YOTA','YOTAR','YOTAU','OLIT','OLITU']"

So with 10,000 tickers/symbols, it would just be longer (more stocks to scrape/pull data from Yahoo Finance).  Hope this explains it okay.  Thank you so much for your help.